# Displaying different content in fancybox and regular page

Tags: php, facebook, fancybox

I dont know a specific term for this issue so here is what I struggle with.

Imagine using fancybox or any other floating window framework on a website. Once a link is clicked, new fancybox instance is created and you see a frame covering your web page. Well there are several occasions when fancybox instance simply cant be initiated (user goes directly to the link, user opens the link in a new tab, javascript is disabled in users browser).

If unsure what exactly I mean, go to facebook and click an image, it opens up in something similar to fancybox , close that and now right click an image and open the link in a new tab. Contents of the fancybox (or whatever facebook uses) are slightly different to the actual page.

How do I go about this using php?

Thank you for ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not realy a PHP issue but more a javascript issue. You can use fancybox by adding the `rel='fancybox'` or `class='fancybox'` attribute on an `a` tag and using the basic functionality. Then it will just open the `href` part in the iframe pop-up. If you open the link in a new tab it will open the `href` part in the new tab.

Now you could also use two seperate links. One for the new tab/no JS link and one for the pop-up. To do that you simple add the new tab link as `href`, so the default behaviour is open the new tab page.

Now to make fancybox open another page you can do several things. One would be to create a completely different link and another would be to append a parameter to the link when its fancybox. The latter will be less efficient for static content like images, so I prefer the first.

now instead of the regular JS to open fancybox do something like:

```
<a href='newtab.html' data-fancylink='fancy.html' class='fancy'>open me</a>
<script>
$('.fancy').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).data('fancylink');
  if (href == undefined) {
    href = $(this).attr('href'); //fall back to default when no fancylink
  }

  $.fancybox({
      'autoScale': true,
      'autoDimensions': true,
      'centerOnScroll': true,
      'type': 'iframe',
      'href': href
  });
});

</script>
```

---

**EDIT** (by JFK) : the general idea is good, however the actual script above won't work without the following tweaks :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancy').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // you still need to prevent default behavior 
        var href = $(this).data('fancylink');
        if (href == undefined) {
            href = this.href; //fall back can be simplified this way
        }
        $.fancybox({
            type: 'iframe',
            href: href
        });
    });
}); // ready
</script>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9ALxd/)**

Comment: Thank you I think that is exactly it. Facebook and also Pinterest use one link for both posibilities so I guess i could do:

<a href='newtab.php' data-fancylink='newtab.php?fancybox=true' class='fancy'>open me</a>

And then on the newtab.php determin through REQUEST or GET whether content is in fancybox or regular page and adjust the site accordingly.

Comment: Since I put the script after the A tag I dont need the ready function. You are right about the preventDefault thing, but to add a complete new script? You should have just put in the comments or alter it.

Comment: @ahojvole. If you want the same page with a param appended, you dont realy need the `data-fancylink=''` part. You can just load the `this.href` part and add the param to the result.

Comment: I didn't add a new script, I just improved yours and commented out the tweaks (and I even up voted your answer.) Regarding the `.ready()` method, it may be obvious for some people but if someone decides to move the script to the `head` section, then it won't work. So far we don't know how many items will be bound through the same selector. Anyways, you can re-edit your answer again and make the changes you would feel happy with.